# Нужно получит переменную извне класса и передать в класс, не используя входящие параметры

Tags: php, ооп

Есть класс:

```
    class list_control
    {

        private $lang;
        private $dbc = $dbc;

        function __construct($lang)
        {
            $this->lang = $lang;
            loadModule('mysql_PDO');
        }

        public function start() {

            $db = new mysql_PDO($this->dbc['host'], $this->dbc['user'], $this->dbc['password'], $this->dbc['dbase']);
            $db->connect();
            $db->query('SELECT * FROM slug');

            load('list', $this->lang);

            $db = null;

        }

    }
```

$dbc - Массив с данными о подключении в бд. Находиться в config.php, который подключен к index.php, и в этой index.php подключен фаил с этим классом. Нужно ***ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО*** сделать так, чтобы не нарушать паттерн.

Comment: Global $dbc. И это плохой паттерн.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильнее будет передать этот масив параметром в метод `start`.

Ну а неправильно - можно использовать директиву `global`

```
public function start() {
  global $dbc;
  $db = new mysql_PDO($dbc['host'], $dbc['user'], $dbc['password'], $dbc['dbase']);
  $db->connect();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Мне скорее подойдёт global, т. к. чтобы в index не делать switch на каждую страницу, что-бы по-разному вызывались методы start

Comment: Если мой ответ помог вам, отметьте его как верный